# Apache POI org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook generating excel report with missing header names

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using apache poi library to dynamically generate excel report. Previously I used HSSFWorkbook class to create excel sheet.when I generated an excel report with a large number of records I got out of memory error issue due to  Garbage collection overload.due to this reason I switched `org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook` and which resolved the previous outofmemory issue.

Here is my code for generating excel report.

```
    public Workbook getReport(String yearLevels, List<User> userList, Map<Long, Date> map) {
            Workbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook (100);
            try {
    
                CellStyle cellStyle1;
                CellStyle cellStyle2;
                Sheet sheet;
    
                HSSFRichTextString cellValue;
                Row row;
                Cell cell;
                Font font1;
                Font font2;
                DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    
                sheet = wb.createSheet("User Details Report");
                sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 7000);
                sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 4000);
                sheet.setColumnWidth(2, 4000);
                sheet.setColumnWidth(3, 4000);
                sheet.setColumnWidth(4, 3000);
                sheet.setColumnWidth(5, 9000);
                font1 = wb.createFont();
                font1.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
                font1.setFontName("Arial");
                font1.setBold(true);
    
                font2 = wb.createFont();
                font2.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
                font2.setFontName("Arial");
    
                cellStyle1 = wb.createCellStyle();
                cellStyle1.setFont(font1);
    
                cellStyle2 = wb.createCellStyle();
                cellStyle2.setFont(font2);
    
                int rowNumber = 0;
    
                CellStyle cellStyle3 = wb.createCellStyle();
                cellStyle3.setFont(font1);
                cellStyle3.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    
                row = sheet.createRow(rowNumber);
                int cellValueCount=0;
    
                Cell userName = row.getCell(cellValueCount, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                userName.setCellValue("Username");
                userName.setCellStyle(cellStyle3);
    
                Cell firstName = row.getCell(cellValueCount++, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                firstName.setCellValue("First Name");
                firstName.setCellStyle(cellStyle3);
    
                Cell lastName = row.getCell(cellValueCount++, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                lastName.setCellValue("Last Name");
                lastName.setCellStyle(cellStyle3);
    
                Cell yearLevel = row.getCell(cellValueCount++, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                yearLevel.setCellValue("Year Level");
                yearLevel.setCellStyle(cellStyle3);
    
                Cell paidStatus = row.getCell(cellValueCount++, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                paidStatus.setCellValue("Student No");
                paidStatus.setCellStyle(cellStyle3);
    
                Cell dateTitleFulfilled = row.getCell(cellValueCount++, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                dateTitleFulfilled.setCellValue("Date Fulfilled");
                dateTitleFulfilled.setCellStyle(cellStyle3);
    
                CellStyle cellStyle4 = wb.createCellStyle();
                cellStyle4.setFont(font2);
                cellStyle4.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    
                int columnNumber = 0;
    
                for (User user : userList) {
                    columnNumber = 0;
                    rowNumber++;
                    row = sheet.createRow(rowNumber);
    
                    cell = row.getCell(columnNumber, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                    cellValue = new HSSFRichTextString(user.getPrincipalId());
                    cell.setCellValue(cellValue);
                    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle4);
                    columnNumber++;
    
                    cell = row.getCell(columnNumber, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                    cellValue = new HSSFRichTextString(user.getFirstName());
                    cell.setCellValue(cellValue);
                    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle4);
                    columnNumber++;
    
                    cell = row.getCell(columnNumber, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                    cellValue = new HSSFRichTextString(user.getLastName());
                    cell.setCellValue(cellValue);
                    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle4);
                    columnNumber++;
    
                    /*cell = row.getCell(columnNumber, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                    cellValue = new HSSFRichTextString(user.getStudentNumber());
                    cell.setCellValue(cellValue);
                    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle4);
                    columnNumber++;*/
    
                    cell = row.getCell(columnNumber, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                    cellValue = new HSSFRichTextString(Integer.toString(user.getYearLevel()));
                    cell.setCellValue(cellValue);
                    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle4);
                    columnNumber++;
    
                    cell = row.getCell(columnNumber, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                    cellValue = new HSSFRichTextString(user.getJppFulfillmentTags());
                    cell.setCellValue(cellValue);
                    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle4);
                    columnNumber++;
    
                    cell = row.getCell(columnNumber, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
    
                    Date date = map.get(user.getId());
    
                    if (date != null) {
                        String eventDate = df1.format(date);
                        cellValue = new HSSFRichTextString(eventDate);
                    } else {
                        cellValue = new HSSFRichTextString("");
                    }
                    cell.setCellValue(cellValue);
                    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle4);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("ReportService::getReport Error Report Creation ", e);
            }
            return wb;
        }
    
    
     ReportService reportService = new ReportService();
            Workbook wb = reportService.getReport(yearLevelsString, userList, map);
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    
            if (request.getParameter("exportAs") == null || !request.getParameter("exportAs").equalsIgnoreCase("xls")) {
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=User_Report.csv");
                CSVPrinter csvPrinter = reportService.writeWorkbookAsCSVToOutputStream(wb, out);
                csvPrinter.flush();
                csvPrinter.close();
            } else {
                response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=User_Report.xls");
                wb.write(out);
                out.close();
            }

public CSVPrinter writeWorkbookAsCSVToOutputStream(Workbook workbook, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(new OutputStreamWriter(out), CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
        try {
            if (workbook != null) {
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Row row = rowIterator.next();
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                        csvPrinter.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }
                    csvPrinter.println();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("ReportService::writeWorkbookAsCSVToOutputStream Error Report Creation ", e);
        }
        return csvPrinter;
    }
```

**After this implementation when I download excel report with more than 100 records I am getting report without header names.**
[image]

**but when I download excel report with less than 100 records I am getting report with cell header name without issue.**
[image]

***Why I the excel report is generating without header names when excel report having more than 100 records?***

Comment: That's how `SXSSFWorkbook` works. `Workbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook (100);` creates a workbook having only 100 rows in random access memory. This are the last 100 created rows. All other rows were streamed into temporary files already and are  not more accessible from workbook iterators. But why creating a `Excel` workbook first and then reading from that workbook to feed a `CSVPrinter`? Why not feed the `CSVPrinter`directly from `List<User> userList` and `Map<Long, Date> map`?

Comment: I think   `Workbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook (100);` is the culprit.  You are requesting more than 100, so the headers is still considered a (Row).  100+1.

Comment: IMHO `SXSSFWorkbook` has a huge design flaw... when trying to write to a row that is not in the working memory it should throw an exception. Instead it silently ignores the write. By getting an exception you would immediately know that your code has a problem to fix.